# Proxing Websocket Traffic from Nginx to Socket.io (without SSL)

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, websocket, socket.io

As of yesterday nginx started to support websocket connections, therefore i was trying to get my nginx-nodejs-socket.io application to work without harproxy ect (not much luck though).

What i want exactly to achieve is nginx to send only websocket connection requests to a backed server,or websocket server ,socket.io to be more exact, while in the same time nginx will be serving php files, and all static content **including html files**.I dont want express to serve static content at all (if this is possible).

Here is my nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        charset UTF-8;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /website/html_public;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }       
        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /website/html_public;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /website/html_public;
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }

         location /connection {
         proxy_pass http://backend;  
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
             }
       }

    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   /website/html_public;
    #        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
}
```

Here is my server.js file in node

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var port    = 8080;

/* HTTP Server*/

server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
app.use(express.logger(':remote-addr - :method :url HTTP/:http-version :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html_public'));
app.use(express.favicon());

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', { layout: false });
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');

});

/*
* Web Sockets
*/
io   = require('socket.io').listen(server),
io.configure('production', function(){
io.enable('browser client etag');
io.set('log level', 1);
io.set('transports', [ 'websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling' ]);
});


console.log('Chat Server started with Node '+ process.version +', platform '+ process.platform + 'to port %d',port);
```

From my client, i try to connect like this :

```
socket = new io.connect('http://localhost/connection');
```

Now, the problem is that when i try to connect normally, typing localhost, i see on chrome console:
`**GET http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)**` , and also when type in the browser `http://localhost/connection` i receive **"Cannot GET /connection"** which is telling me that nginx doesn't proxy websockets normally with my current configuration.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why you want to serve static content through Apache? It is an overhead. Nginx can also do it well [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869001/how-to-serve-all-existing-static-files-directly-with-nginx-but-proxy-to-apache) for example

Comment: @Mustafa
You misunderstood i don't want Apache to do anything cause simply is not present in my project, i use only Nginx, i think you didn't read my question carefully, i showed my nginx.conf file.

Comment: Does your backend respond to `GET /connection` requests? Do you have `/website/html_public/socket.io/socket.io.js` file on your server?

Comment: @VBart
No my backed doesnt respond to GET /connection requests,i have socket.io.js on the server, but it loads only when i type localhost:8080 , when simply type localhost is failing to load the resource (cause nginx doesnt proxy the websocket i assume)

Comment: But you don't configure nginx to proxy on `localhost:8080`. Instead you have configured nginx to proxy on `localhost:8080/connection`. What happens if you type `localhost:8080/connection`?

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, you want:

```
location /connection {
    proxy_pass http://backend/;
    ...
}
```

but you have:

```
location /connection {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    ...
}
```

http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Comment: I changed the nginx config as you proposed, but i still receive the "Cannot GET /connection" message when i type "localhost:8080/connection".I noticed when i type only the ip in my browswer, socket.io cant be loaded, but it loads correctly when type ip:8080.Maybe its my server.js fault, and nginx interfere with express serving the socket.io.js file?Im lost!

Comment: Do you still see `GET http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)` in Chrome console?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.Only when i point browser to localhost:8080 (and from client also localhost:8080) , socket.io.js is resolved normally :/

Comment: Is `socket.io.js` located in `/website/html_public/socket.io/` directory?

Comment: socket.io.js is being called as follows from index.html :
<script type="text/javascript" src="./socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
And when rendered its source is localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js ,is dynamically called from socket.io it self, you think i should call it "directly" and included it in my scripts folder instead?

Comment: `src="./socket.io/socket.io.js"` exactly means that browser must load this script from server. There's no magic.

Comment: Ok there is some improvement now,when i hit localhost:8080/connection (or just localhost) i receive a responce, the client is connected to the socket.io server, i see the handshake in console, but it keeps saying "connecting...", also when i try to send messages it wont actually send them,i see only heartbeats and stuff in console,what can be wrong? (no errors in chrome console)

Comment: Sorry, it's out of my competence. From nginx side it seems all working now, but I'm not familiar with node.js.

Answer (score -1):

Just to make sure, do you have Nginx version 1.3.13 ? ( ex. Nginx's PPA don't have that version yet.)

Comment: yes i compiled it yesterday, here is the link for anyone interested
http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.3.13.tar.gz