# How to serve all existing static files directly with NGINX, but proxy other requests to jetty?

Tags: nginx, proxy

My question is similar to [How to serve all existing static files directly with NGINX, but proxy the rest to a backend server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869001/how-to-serve-all-existing-static-files-directly-with-nginx-but-proxy-to-apache)

different is that my site directory structure looks like this:

```
/nginxRoot/test/js        
/nginxRoot/test/images  
/nginxRoot/test/html
........
```

So the site root isn't "/nginxRoot/" but "/nginxRoot/test/"

I want to nginx to serve all static files that have been put at directories:js,images,html,and proxy other requests to jetty,I have tried:

```
location ~ ^/test/(.*)\.   (jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$
{
    root  /ngixRoot/test;
}

 location ~ ^/test/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

All requests to jetty works,but all requests to static files don't,I doubt they are forwarded to jetty also,is that true?how to fix this problem?

**Update**
Followed the suggestion of @Alexey.Ten

I tried

```
location ~ ^/test/$ {       
   try_files $uri $uri/ @jetty
} 

location @jetty {
    internal;
    add_header X-Local true;
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    proxy_pass              http://$http_host:8080$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache             one;
    proxy_cache_key         backend$request_uri;
    proxy_cache_valid       200  1h;
    proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header;
}
```

but nginx can't be started any more

Comment: Hello,I followed you suggestion,and nginx can't be started anymore

Comment: There is error, that nginx will tell you.

Comment: just told me:* Restarting nginx nginx                                                                      [fail]

Comment: ok,I added a missed ";",and removed " proxy_cache  one;",it got started,but get "403 forbidden" error.

Comment: put **root** directive out of locations, then restart Nginx. Take cache disabled until you get it done.

Comment: After googling,I can't figure out how to do it.would you please tell me how to?